# Disable Save/Submit button after form Reset

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code to enable/disable save button on basis of selection of `facode` but i am having problem that when user after selecting `facode` resets the form, save button is enabled. i want to disable that

```
  $('#save').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#myCoolForm').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $(document).on('change','#facode,#rb_facode',function(){
        if (buttonsDisable($(this).val())) {
            $('#myCoolForm').attr('disabled', false);
            $('#save').attr('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $('#myCoolForm').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#save').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
    function buttonsDisable(e) {
        if (e > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
```

Comment: `$('#save').attr('disabled', false);` here you are enabling the button

Comment: yes i am enabling when facode is selected but i want to disable after resetting the form

Comment: what do you mean by after resetting the form?  you can call `$('#save').attr('disabled', true);` to enable right?

Comment: when user selected facode and then he reset the form, now i want that my save button is again disabled

Comment: keep a flag to decide if the button can be enabled or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("input:reset").on("click", function() {
    this.form.reset(); 
    $('#myCoolForm').attr('disabled', false);
    $('#save').attr('disabled', false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method instead:

```
$('#save').prop('disabled', true); // disabling the button
```

And for enabling the button, use this:

```
$('#save').prop('disabled', false); // enabling the button.
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/prop/